# sphinix search with custom field ordering with relevence

Tags: php, sphinxql

I'm using Sphinx QL for processing results. In my Sphinx Index there are numbers of fields like `sub_cate_name`, `area_name`, `city_name` and `company_priority` etc...

With my company priority field there were 1,2,3,4,5 priority into database. Company having low priority get first via sphinx search (order by priority asc).

I am searching with following query

```
SELECT * FROM sub_cate_index
 WHERE MATCH('(@(sub_cate_name,sub_cate_area,area_name,business_name) "^car dealers$")')
         AND city_name='ahmedabad'
 ORDER BY area_name ASC
 LIMIT 0,100000
 OPTION max_matches=100000, ranker=sph04;
```

I also tried out ORDER BY clause into Sphinx QL, but it would lose relevance of actual keyword search.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use a code block ad format the query for readability

Comment: Which code block i need to use to solve above problem?

Comment: I already did it for you -- do you see  how much more readable your question is now?  If your question is a giant mess most people are not even going to read it let alone try to help you.  Also you should edit your question to make it more clear what you are asking -- what results do you expect -- what results do you get.